# Powershell Copy script which checks File before copying

Tags: powershell

I would like to know how to create a powershell script to copy files from one location another.

The script is required to check a file name before it starts to copy.

The file name is in the current date format (swddmmyyy) eg sw16/11/2011. This file name changes every day so tomorrow it will be sw17112011.

So when the script runs, it checks that the file name matches with the current date before copying the contents from a folder. The file is in the same folder as the contents which require copying.

```
$date = (get-date).adddays(0).ToString("ddMMyyyy") 
$filter = "sw_$date" 
$file = "c:\scripts\$filter" 
$check = test-path $file 
$script = $check -eq $true 
If ($script) {Get-ChildItem C:\scripts*.csv | Copy-Item -destination c:\test}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? show yours efforts and someone surely will help you.

Comment: Christian is right. Give the community something to work with. Which cmdlets do you use?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of info first time. i have since made progress. I'm sure there is probably an easier way but i have foud this method that works

$date = (get-date).adddays(0).ToString("ddMMyyyy")

$filter = "sw_$date"

$file = "c:\scripts\$filter"

$check = test-path $file

$script = $check -eq $true

If ($script) {Get-ChildItem C:\scripts\*.csv | Copy-Item -destination c:\test}

However i would like to understand if there is a way which i could check both folders and then copy only the newer files across? 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better use robocopy for such purposes: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(WS.10).aspx

Comments on the script you were trying:

`(get-date).adddays(0).ToString("ddMMyyyy")` - why do you add 0 days? Just use

`(get-date).tostring("ddMMyyyy")`

You can remove $check, $script etc and just do:

```
If (test-path $file) {Get-ChildItem C:\scripts*.csv | Copy-Item -destination c:\test}
```

Comment: As i would like to to do certain checks (script above) before making the copy, will robocopy do this also? Or do i need to use both powershell and robocopy together?

Answer (score 0):

Yo answer my own question, I have used the following solution.

```
$date = (get-date).ToString("ddMMyyyy")

$filter = "sw_$date"

$file = "c:\scripts\$filter"

If (test-path $file) 

{robocopy c:\scripts c:\test *.csv /xo}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to loop this so it retries if (test-path $file eq false)?